# First figure overlapping the second figure below

Tags: subfloats, vspace, overlap

Using subfigure I want to have two figures on top of each other but at the same time I would like to have the first figure overlapping the second slighty. But with the following code the second figure overlaps the first one. How can I change that? Thanks!

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig1.png}
   \label{fig:Ng1} 
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{-5mm}

\begin{subfigure}{0.55\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{fig2.png}
   \label{fig:Ng2}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[...]{....}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If you aren't adding captions, why do you need subfigues?  Nor will the labels do anything without captions to provide numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses saveboxes to create the subfigures in the correct order (in case you want to add captions).  It uses tikz to position the subfigures and create a bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{figure}[h]
% create subfigures in the correct order
\sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
   \label{fig:Ng1}
\end{subfigure}}%
\sbox1{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
   \label{fig:Ng2} 
\end{subfigure}}%
%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}% use absolute positioning and create a bounding box
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\usebox1};% second subfigure at bottom
    \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,\ht1-10mm) {\usebox0};% first subfigure at top with 10mm overlap
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[...]{....}
\end{figure}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: How could this be extended for 3 figures with the first figure overlapping the second, and the second overlapping the third? Actually I have a grid of 3x3 figures, and so the first 3 figures should overlap the 3 figures in the second row, and the 3 figures in the second row should overlap the 3 figures in the third row. I think my main problem is, that I don't understand how to configure the positioning

Comment: You can use \sbox0 through \sbox9.  After that you will need to use \newsavebox.  Using tikz, positioning should be no problem.  You can also use [right=\columnsep] to space nodes horizontally.  You can use \raisebox instead of tikz to position them, but you will need to calculate the bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be pretty (and maybe not sensible). You have to change the order of the pictures: The second is overlapping the first one, so you have to declare image 2 first!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b}%
        \label{fig:Ng1} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \llap{\raisebox{3cm}{%
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}%
        \label{fig:Ng2}
    \end{subfigure}
    }}
\caption{Figure 2 overlaps Figure 1.}
\end{figure}  

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Yields this:

[image: Figures overlapping.]

Comment: Uh, won't that overlap the top of the figure?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, yes, exactly. Have I misread the question? It is a really hot day, maybe I misunderstood something about »I would like to have the first figure overlapping the second slightly«. Well, the »slightly«-part certainly is debatable …

Comment: I meant the text or top of page will get overlapped.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, oh yes, you are right! In my mind I was working on a beamer presentation and didn't even consider there would be text around the figures. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there will be text around the figures :(

Comment: @HighwayJohn, I did some more research and have come up with a new attempt. Have a look and let me know.